# How to efficiently save data to a remote server database (python)

Tags: python, django

Currently in my code, there are a few client machines doing processing and one server machine with a database. After an individual client machine finishes processing some data, it saves the data to a .txt file and sftp's it over to the server.

The server has a job that just waits for these txt files and stores the data into a database.

I wanted to know of any other efficient processes for this, kinda a python beginner. Is there a way to remotely save data into the database of the server? How to do so securely, etc?

To be more specific, this project is a webapp hosted in django. I know how to use django's standalone scripts to save data into a db, just preferably need to know how to do so remotely.

Thank you.

Comment: Why storing it in .txt, sftping it and saving it to the database? Can't just the clients connect to the db and save it?

Comment: Yes, i was thinking that. I just wanted to know the best way how to. Since im using django there may be a shortcut.

Comment: which database server are you using..?

Comment: creation text file and saving data from it its not a good way, you can use python mysql client to save data directly mysql and it is best way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django databases can be remote - there is no requirement they be on the same host at the django server. Just set an appropriate `HOST` and `PORT`. See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/databases/#id10

Update: Based on your comment, I understand that you want to write python/django code that will run in the browser, and connect to a remote database. There is no practical way of doing this. Have the data sent back to your server, and forward it on from there.

Update 2: If you are able to distribute software outside of the browser, you could have a small django deployment on each client computer, which the user connects to through their browser, which could connect directly to the database. Obviously, security considerations apply.

Comment: Thanks, but i'm fine with the db being on the django server. I just want to know how to have my client scripts connect to the django server, preferably using django's own model syntax, like Model(field1="", field2="").save().

Comment: @LucasOu-Yang You mean, you want to write python code to be executed in the browser?

Comment: @LucasOu-Yang I've added a sentence about an alternate architecture which might help if it's suitable for your particular case.

Comment: For Mysql-python, how do I know which port my database is on?

Comment: @LucasOu-Yang It's up to your setup. It could be any port.